# How to use brush jitter in a GIMP Python script

Tags: python, gimp

In the brush options in the GIMP UI there is "jitter".
How can I use that in a GIMP python script?.
I can't find the equivalent context setting in the procedure browser.
Would I have to define that via dynamics?

Comment: If you are stoking path, there is a script to add randomness: see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230116153112/https://gimplearn.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3345).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the scripts there are not archived.

Answer (score 1):

Some options are laking in the PDB api - and are still lacking in the upcoming GIMP 3.0  -
It is possible (but I can't promise) -  I can work on these - there is an open feature request on GIMP's gitlab here - please, comment on the issue for your needs, or if you have constructive ideas - https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/5041